# Laravel mysql migrate error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.6

I recently format my mac book pro, after cloning the proyect from github and install the things I need like MySql and Sequel Pro I tried to migrate the database information but I get this error:

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1231 Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = fisica and table_name = migrations)

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1231 Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER'")
```

Versions:

Mysql  8.0.11

Laravel 5.6.12

PHP 7.1.14 (cli)

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=fisica
DB_USERNAME=xxx
DB_PASSWORD=xxx
```

I created the database from Sequel PRO GUI

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594594/no-auto-create-user-error-while-installing-drupal-7

Comment: Seems like You need to do something like (as root user): `GRANT ALL ON fisica.* TO 'username_here'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'password_here'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Comment: Can you add the top portion of your dump file to your question?

Comment: @DavidBrossard I have mysql 8.0.11 so, i don't think so.

Comment: @num8er i will try!

Answer (score 204, accepted):

I finally found the solutions a days ago and I remembered this post.
In the `config/database.php` file in mysql tag, the sql modes should be added in order to skip this error. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-full

My MySQL array ended up like this:

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'modes'  => [
            'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',
            'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
            'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
            'NO_ZERO_DATE',
            'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
            'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION',
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: For me, I only had to add the `modes` key and array values to my config.

Comment: I have MySQL 8, and adding this tag "modes" all worked correctly. Thanks!

Comment: I am wondering if there's any other command that needs to be run after adding the modes to the connection array before this works, I added the modes and tried to run php artisan migrate but I am met with the same error

Comment: after that use command : `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: dont forget to run composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 27):

In file:

> config/database.php

```
'mysql' =[
    ...
    'strict' => false
]
```

Also disable sql_mode 
via SQL:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

via my.cnf inside heading `[mysqld]`

```
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Test the changes:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';
```

Comment: strict => false fixed it for me. and is much easier to remember than setting the "modes" array. Thanks.

Comment: Nice, its work for me, just change for false. Tks

Answer (score 15):

Effectively you must add this code at the end of **each of the connections you have with the mysql driver**

```
'modes' => [
             'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',
             'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
             'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
             'NO_ZERO_DATE',
             'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
             'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION',
         ],
```

Answer (score 8):

That SQL Mode is not supported in your version of MYSQL. It was removed in version 8.0. The last version to support this sql mode was 5.8. Your MYSQL Version could be 8 or later. (Laravel should update too)

Comment out or delete that line from your `config/database.php` file

```
mysql' => [
  ...
  'modes' => [
    ...
    //'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
],
```

Answer (score 6):

I experienced the above situation after upgrading laravel from 5.3 to 5.7 with it previously working with MySQL 8 without any problems the accepted answer did not work for me and after googling around I did not find a solution. what worked for me was searching my project folder

```
grep -rnw 'Location_to_your_project_folder' -e 'sql_mode'
```

Which lead me to

```
~/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php:183:return "set session sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'";
```

Once I removed the `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER` from the list everything worked again.

Comment: i know this is old, but i came across this today, after trying all the solutions listed above, this is the only thing that worked for me.  Not the best idea to edit vendor files, but this is local (where as live is running mysql5.6 so all good for me :) )

Answer (score 3):

In reading the mysql 8.0 documentation it looks like the NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER was removed from sql-mode.  I suspect your my.cnf has this referenced and should be removed from your conf and any mysql setting internally and your mysqld restarted.

Keep in mind, I haven't upgraded to mysql 8.0 and just reading documentation.  I'm happy using 5.6.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-nutshell.html

> Using GRANT to create users. Instead, use CREATE USER. Following this practice makes the NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER SQL mode immaterial for GRANT statements, so it too is removed.

Comment: A combination of this an @eValdezate's answer helped me

Answer (score 3):

MySQL 8 is not supported.
I had the same problem and had to use a lower MySQL version (5.7).

In MySQL 8, the option "NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER" was removed from the "sql_mode" parameter and Laravel is looking for that.

Answer (score 2):

I came across same problem today with `mysql 8`, `php 8`, `laravel 8`

**Solution**

i just updated my `config/database` file and changed `strict` from `true` to `false` in following section

```
    'mysql' => [
        ...
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
        ...
    ],
```

and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 5.5 and greater tries to auto detect the mysql server version and if mysql 8.0.11 or greater, it leaves out `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER` from the modes. However, in my case it was incorrectly detecting the version as `5.6.47.0`. In laravel 7 they added the ability to override the version check by manually setting the version in `config/database.php`

```php
'mysql' => [
    // ...
    'strict' => true,
    'version' => '8.0.11',
]
```

On laravel versions less than 7.x the easiest solution is to set `'strict' => false`

Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php

```php
protected function strictMode(PDO $connection, $config)
{
    $version = $config['version'] ?? $connection->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_SERVER_VERSION);

    if (version_compare($version, '8.0.11') >= 0) {
        return "set session sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'";
    }

    return "set session sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'";
}
```

Answer (score -3):

My problem was a misspelled database name in the config.